# How to run an infinite blocking process in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a set of API endpoints in Express. One of them receives a request and starts a long running process that blocks other incoming Express requests.

My goal to make this process non-blocking. To understand better inner logic of Node Event Loop and how I can do it properly, I want to replace this long running function with my dummy long running blocking function that would start when I send a request to its endpoint.

I suppose, that different ways of making the dummy function blocking could cause Node manage these blockings differently.

So, my question is - how can I make a basic blocking process as a function that would run infinitely?

Comment: What is the process doing? Network, IO?

Comment: It's a recursive function that just processes some data without external IO.

Comment: @SergeiBasharov have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32101398/how-to-block-process-and-wait-for-result-on-node-js

Comment: you can use [Sockets](https://socket.io/) events to handle the backend processes and return the response something like 'event started' at the very same moment and then you can keep checking if the process ended with another api.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *node-webworker-threads*.

```
    var Worker, i$, x$, spin;

    Worker = require('webworker-threads').Worker;

    for (i$ = 0; i$ < 5; ++i$) {
      x$ = new Worker(fn$);
      x$.onmessage = fn1$;
      x$.postMessage(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 30));
    }
    (spin = function(){
      return setImmediate(spin);
    })();

    function fn$(){
      var fibo;
      fibo = function(n){
        if (n > 1) {
          return fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2);
        } else {
          return 1;
        }
      };

      return this.onmessage = function(arg$){
        var data;
        data = arg$.data;
        return postMessage(fibo(data));
      };
    }

    function fn1$(arg$){
      var data;
      data = arg$.data;
      console.log("[" + this.thread.id + "] " + data);
      return this.postMessage(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 30));
    }
```

https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads

Answer (score 0):

> So, my question is - how can I make a basic blocking process as a function that would run infinitely?

```
 function block() {
   // not sure why you need that though
   while(true);
 }
```

> I suppose, that different ways of making the dummy function blocking could cause Node manage these blockings differently.

Not really. I can't think of a "special way" to block the engine differently.

> My goal to make this process non-blocking.

If it is really that long running you should really offload it to another thread.

Comment: Thank you Jonas, I think it's something I need. Why I need is because first I want to make the dummy function being unaltered from inside to work as an unblocking function and as this is a new area for me, I read that I can use different ways to make it unblocking, e.g. via `setImmediate` or other alternatives. The process takes about 2-3 minutes.

Comment: @sergei yes, you could split up the task into multiple short running ones, and then use a short timer to shedule the next task at the end of the event queue

Answer (score 0):

There are short cut ways to do a quick fix if its like a one time thing, you can do it using a npm module that would do the job.

But the right way to do it is setting up a common design pattern called 'Work Queues'. You will need to set up a queuing mechanism, like rabbitMq, zeroMq, etc. How it works is, whenever you get a computation heavy task, instead of doing it in the same thread, you send it to the queue with relevant id values. Then a separate node process commonly called a 'worker' process will be listening for new actions on the queue and will process them as they arrive. This is a worker queue pattern and you can read up on it here:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html

I would strongly advise you to learn this pattern as you would come across many tasks that would require this kind of mechanism. Also with this in place you can scale both your node servers and your workers independently.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly your 'long processing' is, but in general you can approach this kind of problem in two different ways.

**Option 1:**

Use the `webworker-threads` module as @serkan pointed out. The usual 'thread' limitations apply in this scenario. You will need to communicate with the Worker in messages.

This method should be preferable only when the logic is too complicated to be broken down into smaller independent problems (explained in option 2). Depending on complexity you should also consider if native code would better serve the purpose.

**Option 2:**

Break down the problem into smaller problems. Solve a part of the problem, schedule the next part to be executed later, and yield to let NodeJS process other events.

For example, consider the following example for calculating the factorial of a number.

Sync way:

```
function factorial(inputNum) {
    let result = 1;
    while(inputNum) {
        result = result * inputNum;
        inputNum--;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Async way:

```
function factorial(inputNum) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let result = 1;
        const calcFactOneLevel = () => {
            result = result * inputNum;
            inputNum--;
            if(inputNum) {
                return process.nextTick(calcFactOneLevel);
            }
            resolve(result);
        }
        calcFactOneLevel();
    }
}
```

The code in second example will not block the node process. You can send the response when returned promise resolves.